# T-SQL (Access) remove all duplicates but one with highest ID

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, duplicates

I have problem with duplicates in my base but I can't use distinct select to other table becouse I have unique data in some colums. I want to keep last rating.
Example:

```
ID| ProductName | Code | Rating
------|------ | ------ | ------
1| Bag | 1122 | 5
2| Car| 1133 | 2
3| Bag | 1122 | 3
4| Car | 1133 | 1
5| Train| 1144 | 1
```

As result of query I want to get:

```
ID| ProductName | Code | Rating
------|------ | ------ | ------
3| Bag | 1122 | 3
4| Car | 1133 | 1
5| Train| 1144 | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a `GROUP BY` to identify the id values of the most recent duplicates for each `Code/ProductName` group:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Code, MAX(ID) AS ID
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Code
) t2
    ON t1.Code = t2.Code AND
       t1.ID   = t2.ID
```

Comment: Thank You for help with this case and code formatting!